# How to include or insert hash (#) on PHP location header or direct/link to an id of a webpage

Tags: php, location

I`m wokring on jquery mobile webpage with a form using PHP & mysql. Basically what I am trying to do is to redirect the result of form processing back to the main webpage (formProcessor.php#email). This is the code where I'm having a problem:

```
if ($result) { 
    ("Location: formProcessor.php#email");  
    exit;
}
```

However, I am having an "error loading file" while submitting the form from the mobile webpage. When I inspect formProcessor.php#email, Im having a 404 error. PHPmyadmin can receive the files submitted from the form. I think can retrieve the data from the database table but i cant go back to that particular link on webpage ("Location: formProcessor.php#email").

I am speculating that "Location: formProcessor.php#email" is invalid and ends after .php. It does not direct it to that particular link of the webpage (#email") where my form is. So

What's the valid syntax to use?

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     header('Location: formProcessor.php#email');
```

And make sure you do not output any html tag through anyway before this line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *absolutely* not sure this is your (main/only) problem, but according to [RFC2616 sec 14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) `Location` response-header field MUST provide an *absolute URI*:

```
   Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
```

Still as *per* RFC2616, "absolute URIs always begin with a scheme name followed by a colon." -- i.e.: `http://hostname/path/to/ressource`

Comment: I think I have to recheck the whole code. I will study this for sure. thanks

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function :

```
if ($result) { 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/");  
    exit;
}
```

Then, use absolute path like `http://nameofyoursite.com/yourpage`